# PHP5 + MongoDB 2.6 + PHP driver 1.5.1 - C10k Apache worker/prefork

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, scalability, php-mongodb

We're currently moving to a production environment (MongoDB + PHP) and while testing concurrency (using loader.io) I face difficulties reaching the 10k concurrent connections.

My test script was very basic, just a simple MongoClient::construct to connect to the database and a static echo.

I tried both MPMs in apache without success:
1. Prefork + mod_php - Bottleneck is not the connections, rather the memory - each php process used ~200M - Not scalable at all.
2. Worker + PHP-FPM - After ~2000-3000 connections I start seeing many errors both on the PHP machine regarding no candidate servers as well as the DB stating too many connections.

I'm kinda stuck here. 
I thought about giving NGINX a shot, but seems as it'll fall short the same as option #2 above did.

Could that be achieved at all? Allowing more than 10k connections in this configuration (PHP+MongoDB)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this is your question ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried every possible configuration as I mentioned and couldn't get the scale we need...

Comment: What exactly was taking 200m in the prefork+mod_php combo? That seems highly unlikely. And the errors you got in the nginx+fpm combo also seem very unlikely, did anything show up in the mongod error logs? What was your test script? Are you connecting to ReplicaSet? mongos? each mongod proccess supports 20k connections without any issues (each socket uses 4mb though, so you better have plenty ram when reaching that limit)...